# UTF-8 in java applet in browser

Tags: java, utf-8, applet

I have a problem with encoding in java applet. When I am running it in NetBeans, russian characters in applet are ok. No encoding problems. But, when I am running the same applet through browser, then my russian characters are shown as squares(encoding problem).

Where is the problem?

I have russian translations in .properties files, which has UTF-8 encoding. Also I tried to convert them to UTF-8 using

```
value = new String(bundle.getString(cLabel).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF8");
```

Some ideas?

Comment: You need font to display those characters

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But why then are they displayed in NetBeans correctly?

Comment: Try setting the same font as you have set it in your netbeans or try setting arial unicode font in your browser it should display if there is no other problem

Comment: The problem is not in font. I have the same font in NetBeans and in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, .properties files are plain ISO8859-1, and any characters not represented there must be encoded via escape sequences, see the native2ascii program that comes with the JDK on how to convert them.

Comment: (As for 2023) Or just insert `\<ascii code>` inside your string to get new chars. For example `drawString("caf\u00E9")` renders `café` (coffee in Portuguese).

Answer (score 0):

Pass this property to your applet:

```
java_arguments="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
```

(note that depending on the html code you use, the syntax might be different, but the attribute name is `java_arguments` and the value is `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`)

Comment: AFAIK this can be done only on signed applets. Unfortunately my applet is not signed.

Comment: Hm, give it a try. It's true that I've used it only on signed applets, but I don't immediately see why you shouldn't be able to set it.